# Xamarin Android Apps and Azure SQL Databases

Tags: c#, android, rest, azure, xamarin.android

I'm a second year student and for my last project I'm interested in doing a `Xamarin` Application. So I just got started with Xamarin and I've been doing the tutorials in `developer.xamarin` to learn new things. However my ultimate goal is to make an `Xamarin.Android` App which has multiple screens which will be used to interact with an Azure `SQLDatabase` which is already being used for my `ASP.NET` Forms Website, so that I can use both like Facebook to as an App as well as an Website.

While I was searching for examples I got this by Xamarin [This Link](https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/) (Which is quite complicated and some unknown errors pop while I'm developing it) but, while I was reading the forums I got this [C-Sharp Corner Tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-create-login-with-web-api-using-azure-sql-server-part-one/) which is quite easier than the original Xamarin Blog Example. Later I found another approach given in StackOverflow which is [Hosted In GitHub.](https://github.com/brminnick/XamList) It would be grate if someone could explain me what is the correct approach (and what is used in the Industry) from above three and which is the most optimal solution for my app goal.

Plus, According to the articles I read, here's what I understood so far, It is unsafe to directly connect an Azure SQL Database to an Android App like we used to do in ASP.NET applications so what we usually do is use *Some Mechanism called REST based on Json requests*.  It would be great if someone could tell`What is the way to interact an Android Application with an Azure SQL database`

Thanking in advance :-)

Comment: You could refer to : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93842/xamarin-android-with-azure-sql-database

Comment: Thanks, however can we achieve the same result by article [Consuming a RESTful Web Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/) and its back-end article from MSFT [ASP.NET Core Back-end](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mobile/native-mobile-backend) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really easy way to  do this by using the example officially provided by Xamarin about `Consuming a RESTful Service` which can be found in [Consuming a RESTful Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/) and developing its [ASP.NET Core Back-end API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mobile/native-mobile-backend) which can be found in above URL which is provided my Microsoft

Thanks